# How can I make a gradle from a Library Project Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, codebase

I am using Android Studio.
I have created a library project.and I have successfully included this library in another prstoject.I have followed the below steps to include that library in my project.

a.I have added that library folder in my project root folder.

b.In settings.gradle file include ':library'
c.In build.gradle file compile project(':library')

Now I want to **add library as a gradle file**.I want to implement just one line in build.gradle file compile **'com.example.library'** and then I can access that library files etc.I don't want to add the library folder in my project.Because when the library folder gets increased at that time my project size is also get increased which is not beneficial for me.So guys please suggest me how can I achieve this.How can I get that gradle file or if you have any idea please suggest me.

Comment: are you willing to share that library to public or use it only for private purposes?

Comment: I was just about to add the below link posted by wonderkid..Best post to answer your question!

Comment: I want to use it for private purpose

Comment: you could go through the post provided in the answer below to understand how it works and then look out for private maven repository providers out there like nexus,artifactory,etc..

Answer (score 0):

Read this. This might help. [How to distribute your own Android library through jCenter and Maven Central from Android Studio](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)